# When open my asp.net site in Chrome on a newly started computer with Windows Vista the webpage load very slow/vista stops for a while?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, windows-vista

When open my asp.net site in Chrome on a newly started computer with Windows Vista the webpage load very slow/vista stops for a while? It works fine in windows7 with chrome. Can it be something wrong with chrome and Vista, or is it something wrong with my website?

Comment: What do you see in the Network tab?

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I'm using fonts from Typekit on the website, I removed it and then the site works fine. But I don't understand what the problem is with typekit combined with my site. (I've decided not to use it now, don't need it). Another thing, I saw your @SLaks Jquery-tutorial. Very nice :)